# Bluetooth HFP connection with Iphone, Droid

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth

We are developing a Bluetooth hands-free module in windows CE. We are able to establish successful hands-free connection with a number of phones (Samsung, LG, nokia) and able to receive ‘RING’ message on call alert.

But for Iphone (iphone4), after establishing a successful hfp connection, we are getting a ‘U’ message in reply to any AT commands instead of ‘OK’ or ‘ERROR’ message.
What may be the reason for this?

For DROID phones my device is detected as a hands-free device but I am not able to establish an hfp connection with it.

Regards,
Swdeveloper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about HFP but I've done plenty with AT-command driven devices. The "U" you're receiving could be a misinterpreted "OK" if your bits/speed/parity - or some related setting - are incorrect.